# error: swscale headers not found! Install FFmpeg or Libav

Tags: c++, ubuntu, networking, swscale

I want to compile OpenMCU.ru on my Ubuntu box, when I run `./configure` command, following error appears:

```
checking for swscale.h... no
checking for libswscale/swscale.h... no
checking for ffmpeg/swscale.h... no
checking for libav/swscale.h... no
checking for ffmpeg/libswscale/swscale.h... no
checking for libav/libswscale/swscale.h... no
configure: error: swscale headers not found! Install FFmpeg or Libav.
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install `libswscale-dev` package:

```
apt-get install libswscale-dev
```